# How to cast shadow to an object which is inside a sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a object which is inside a sphere. I want to use light on the object and the shadow should be displayed on the sphere. I have used SpotLight and checked but it didn't work. Suggest me how I can set lights and which type of light is best suited for shadows.
This is my code:

```js
var group1 = new THREE.Group();
var obj = new THREE.Object3D();
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( 'obj.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
    
    var phongMaterials = materials.map( function ( material ) { 
        return new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
            color: new THREE.Color( material.color ),
            shading: THREE.FlatShading,
            shininess: 50,
            //specular: 0xc00162
            //wireframe: true
        } )
    } );    
    
    obj = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( phongMaterials )
    );
   
    obj.castShadow = true;
    
    scene.add(obj);
    group1.add( obj );
    
    group1.position.set( 0, -180, -150 );
    group1.rotation.set( 0, Math.PI/2, 0 );
    group1.scale.set( 20, 20, 20 );
        
} );

scene.add( group1 );

//Sphere
group = new THREE.Group();
sphereMesh = new THREE.Group();

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color   : 0xffffff,
//    emissive   : 0xffffff,
    transparent: true,
    opacity    : 0.5,
   
});

material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

var icogeo = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(70,3);
icogeo.verticesNeedUpdate=true;
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(icogeo, material);
sphere.receiveShadow = true;
group.add(sphere);
group.position.z=150;
scene.add(group);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here are the materials you should look at to help you achieve EXACTLY you want to do and I mean EXACTLY:

- [For the concept of shadow mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping) (just food for thought)
- The actual [tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/20/casting-shadows/) for casting shadows with three.js (its very straight foward).

Good luck

Comment: Awesome, please upvote answer and mark the question as solved.